# Why does st_blksize differ when using fstat on STDOUT_FILENO compared to stat on a regular file?

Tags: c, system-calls, stat

Why st_blksize differ for regular file and stdout?

I write a little program, where there's a lot of output.
There was decision on my part to move aside stdio.h and FILE struct and use some syscalls.

Question arised on what buffer size to use.
First idea - obtain st_blksize member of stat structure and use it as a buffer's size.

When I use stat and pass to it argv[0] I get st_blksize of 4096.
But when I use fstat and pass to it STDOUT_FILENO - I get st_blksize of 1024.

```
stat(argv[0], &buf_stat);
printf("%zu\n", (size_t)buf_stat.st_blksize);
```

^ this prints 4096

```
fstat(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf_stat);
printf("%zu\n", (size_t)buf_stat.st_blksize);
```

^ this prints 1024

The question is - why do they differ?
I thought that blksize is pretty much universal for the whole system.

And a bonus question - what literature to read on optimising I/O using syscalls? Some general advice on this topic will be great too.

Comment: Provided two snippets.

Comment: I don't see any particular reason the blocks used for on-disk filesystem storage should be the same as the blocks used for in-memory character devices. They're doing completely different things. What happens if you run the same program with stdout redirected to a file?

Comment: Ah, I see. Basically, file types are different, that's why they are different.

Comment: You could look at "SFIO - safe and fast string/file io" by David Korn et al. Maybe also look into memory mapped I/O and asynchronous I/O. But why bother? Is your application really I/O bound by stdio?